# Can't change the width of table <TD>

Tags: css, html, html-table

The blue table data entry won't reside its width. Is there a new html5 way to be able to achieve this feat? The row should be the same width as the photo above it.

```html
  <div class="template" style="text-align:center">
    <table  width="100%" and height="100%" BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 align="center">
  <tr>
   <td width='100%' height='100%' bgcolor='#f2f3f4'>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <img src ="https://image.ibb.co/i4ykZk/roverlogo.png" alt="RoverLogo">
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 
<!-- Background photo   -->

 <TABLE width="80%" BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0" align="center">
 <TR>

     <TD WIDTH="997" HEIGHT="326" 
        background="https://image.ibb.co/dO1HfQ/dog3edit.jpg" style="background-
        image:url(https://image.ibb.co/dO1HfQ/dog3edit.jpg); background-repeat: 
        no-repeat;">

    <!-- <b>WELCOME TO ROVER! </b> -->
    <FONT class="titletext" color="white" align="center" style="width: 800px;
    font-size: 50px;"><b>WELCOME TO ROVER!</b></FONT><br><br> 
    <FONT class="subtitletext" color="white" align="center" style="width: 
       100px;
    font-size: 30px;">Ready to get started?</FONT><br><br><br>
 
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/nvbiLQ/button.png" 
       alt="Button" border="0"></a>
 
   </TD>

 </TR>
 <tr>
     <td width="80%" bgcolor="#blue" style="width:80%">
     </td>
 </tr>
 </TABLE>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think you want a table here. Tables aren't really semantically correct when used to create a layout. Make use of CSS. That would be the HTML5 way.

Comment: The layout I am creating to create will be used as a email template. Email's have a different sense of "semantically correct", but what CSS would you use? I have tried using inline CSS and it hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
article {
  width: 100%;
}

#banner {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/dO1HfQ/dog3edit.jpg") no-repeat no-repeat;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1, p {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  background: #00c55c;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}

#logo {
  background: #f2f3f4;
}

#logo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<article>
    
    <section id="logo">
       <img src ="https://image.ibb.co/i4ykZk/roverlogo.png" alt="RoverLogo">
    </section>    
    
    <section id="banner">
      
      <h1>Welcome to Rover!</h1>
      <p>Ready to get started?</p>
      <button>Search Sitters</button>
    
    </section>
    
</article>
```

I'd do something like this. No table for layout. If it has to be inline, just put a `<style></style>` tag above the HTML block.

Comment: This would be an ideal solution for a web page. Unfortunately most email servers block out the "body" portion in a email and so I use a table with 100% w/h to get a background color for the email. The background color is suppose to be gray.

Comment: I set the width of the article element. No more body tag.

Answer (score 1):

For the background color of the button i used the following website.

https://flatuicolors.com/

I also made everything separated into css and html so you could see. No inline CSS. This is the proper way to use tables, and headers.

Use a `<div>` tag for the headers as it automatically pushes things to a new line after it. No need for the break tag. The break tag is rarely used in design anymore.

Also i made sure that your separator line is blue.

I believe there are better ways of accomplishing this WITHOUT tables, however you said you needed this in table form, so here ya go!

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}

.background {
background: url('https://image.ibb.co/dO1HfQ/dog3edit.jpg');
}
.titletext {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.subtitletext {
  font-size: 30px;
}

button {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #27ae60;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}


.seperator {
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<TABLE>
  <TR class="background">
    <TD>
      <div class="titletext">WELCOME TO ROVER!</div>
      <div class="subtitletext">Ready to get started?</div>
      <a href="#"><button>Search Sitters</button></a>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <tr>
    <td class="seperator""></td>
  </tr>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: I currently have a table inside of a table and need to use inline css within the style attribute. Is there a way to define css for more than one table?

Comment: use an id in the table tag. `<table id="tablename">`... then use the id selector in CSS `#tablename` to select that table. If doing inline CSS, just use the style attribute. `<table style="background: blue; width: 80%;">`

Comment: @RossRhone if you found this information helpful please mark it as the answer. and don't forget to upvote!

Comment: I have found the root of the problem! Within my <TR> i have  style="background-image:url(https://image.ibb.co/dO1HfQ/dog3edit.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;" The no-repeat cuts off the repeating part of the photo, thus cutting the width to the user. The blue box now is longer than the photo. Is there a way to keep that width moving to the match the size of the photo?

Comment: The width of what element? I would generally use view width `width: 80vw` for 80 percentage of the view width of the screen.

Comment: Try running the code with style="background-repeat: no-repeat" and then run it without that code. You will see how the blue box matches the width of the code without the no-repeat code.

Comment: In the above code snippet, no where do i use that property. No need to. If you have another question please post another question, but seeing how this question has been answered, please choose the correct answer out of the three and mark as solved. Thanks. :P

Answer (score 0):

You are using inline css,Try this:

`<TABLE  style="width="80%" BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0" align="center"";>`